# Providing Maven values at runtime

Tags: maven

I’m using this suite to run tests in maven
 
This is working fine.

Is there a way to give parallel and thread-count values at command line?!!

Comment: Sorry think there will be much more information required to be able to answer your questions. E.g. which suite are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The maven surefire (and probably failsafe) plugins offer numerous so-called User Properties that can be supplied to `mvn` using the `-D` parameter, i.e.,

```
mvn clean install -Dparallel=all -DthreadCount=5
```

See documentation for the `surefire:test` goal: [`threadCount`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#threadCount) and [`parallel`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel).

Comment: I did that. When I go with surefire:test goal, no tests were getting picked up

Comment: Do you have surefire tests? Or do you need maveby-failsafe, as your test classes have an `ITCase` suffix instead of `Test`? What happens when you run the `install` phase? Are tests executed then?

Comment: But I agree with Joerg, we can only guess when you provide such little information

Comment: So is this one then solved and we continue with your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903460/surefiretest-goal-not-picking-tests)?

Comment: I'm sorry, How can I figure whether the tests are surefire tests. I run the suite by mentioning in the pom.xml.

             <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.22.0</version>
               <configuration>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                  <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                 </suiteXmlFiles>
               </configuration>
             </plugin>

Comment: Here are the naming conventions for [surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html). Not sure about the `suiteXmlFile` and of this is needed / hurts. But that's all not related to this question.

Comment: @Devopsthings if this helped to solve your problem, please use the checkmark on the left to mark this as solved.