# Surefire:test goal not picking tests

Tags: jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

With Maven, when I run the ‘test’ goal, tests are processed.
When I run the ‘surefire:test’ goal, tests are not processed.

However, I’ve mentioned the surefire plugin this way in pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>foo.xmlxml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: Syntax enhancements

Comment: Is you file really named foo.xml***xml***? What's its content? Does `mvn test` execute any tests if you remove the configuration?

Comment: SmallTestSuite.xml

Comment: I would like to execute the surefire:test for re-run of failed tests....Is there any way I can re-run for ‘test’ goal

Comment: As a workaround try `test-compile surefire:test`